# Strange shift of a shadow while it's near left side of screen- CSS / JS / PerspectiveTransform

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, shadow

I used [PerspectiveTransform.js](https://github.com/edankwan/PerspectiveTransform.js) for counting a shadow:

```
$("#" + this.id + "_shadow").css({
    "width" : this.w,
    "height" : this.h
});

// create PerspectiveTransfrom
var transform = new PerspectiveTransform(document.getElementById(this.id + "_shadow"), this.w, this.h, true);

// the properties represent the 4 corners are "topLeft", "topRight", "bottomLeft" and "bottomRight"
transform.topRight.x = (this.w * 1.5);
transform.topLeft.x = (this.w / 1);
transform.topRight.y = (this.h / 1.7);
transform.topLeft.y = (this.h / 1.7);
```

This is css class .shadow:

```
.shadow{
    position: absolute;
    filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%);
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

And this shadow as every object is moving in the opposite direction than player:

```
Draw(){
    if(shadows === true){
        $("#" + this.id + "_shadow").css({
            "left" : this.x - player.pos_x,
            "top" : this.y - player.pos_y
        });
    }
}
```

And when shadow is near to the left side of a screen, strange thing is happening.

This is normal look of an object and a shadow:

[image: picture]

This is look of object and a shadow when they're near to the left side of a screen:

[image: picture]

When shadow is really near the left side of a screen:

[image: picture]

It's cutted, and it doesn't look good.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: I tested it on Firefox and I realized it's not happening, on Chrome it is.